# Android MediatorLiveData to combine multiple LiveData results into single LiveData object (In Java)

Tags: android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, mediatorlivedata, android-livedata-transformations

I am using 2 `LiveData`s from separate tables into the repository of my application. I add the two `LiveData`s as sources to the `CustomMediatorLiveData` class which extends `MediatorLiveData`.
In the `onChanged` callback of `addSource` method for each `LiveData`, I send the values of both the `LiveData`s into a method that combines both and returns a single `LiveData` which is set as the `value` for the `CustomMediatorLiveData` object. I am creating an object of this `CustomMediatorLiveData` in my Repository and passing the two `LiveData`s as parameters for the constructor.

This runs and doesn't give any error but it is messing up the data within the LiveData itself.

example: If the date was originally 15th August 2020 then it can be something like 14th August 0001.

CustomMediatorLiveData:

```java
public class CustomMediatorLiveData extends MediatorLiveData<List<Object>> {
    private List<Note> notes = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<RecurringTask> recurringTasks = Collections.emptyList();

    public CustomMediatorLiveData(LiveData<List<Note>> liveNotes, LiveData<List<RecurringTask>> liveRecurringTasks) {
        addSource(liveNotes, notes1 -> {
            if (notes1 != null) {
                this.notes = notes1;
            }
            setValue(combineData(notes,recurringTasks));
        });

        addSource(liveRecurringTasks, recurringTasks1 -> {
            if (recurringTasks1 != null) {
                this.recurringTasks = recurringTasks1;
            }
            setValue(combineData(notes,recurringTasks));
        });
    }


    // This method adds the 2 lists into one and sorts them based on dates and priority.
    
    private List<Object> combineData(List<Note> notes, List<RecurringTask> recurringTasks) {
        List<Object> combinedList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (notes != null && !notes.isEmpty())
            combinedList.addAll(notes);
        if(recurringTasks!=null && !recurringTasks.isEmpty())
        combinedList.addAll(recurringTasks);

        Collections.sort(combinedList, new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Date d1, d2;
                Note n1 = null, n2 = null;
                RecurringTask r1 = null, r2 = null;

                if (o1 instanceof Note && o2 instanceof Note) {
                    int hmm = Boolean.compare(((Note) o2).isPriority(), ((Note) o1).isPriority());
                    if (hmm != 0)
                        return hmm;
                }

                if (o1 instanceof Note) {
                    d1 = ((Note) o1).getEnd_date();
                    n1 = ((Note) o1);
                } else {
                    d1 = ((RecurringTask) o1).getEnd_date();
                    r1 = ((RecurringTask) o1);
                }

                if (o2 instanceof Note) {
                    d2 = ((Note) o2).getEnd_date();
                    n2 = ((Note) o2);
                } else {
                    d2 = ((RecurringTask) o2).getEnd_date();
                    r2 = ((RecurringTask) o2);
                }

                if (n1 != null) {
                    if (r2 != null) {
                        if (n1.isPriority()) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (n2 != null) {
                    if (r1 != null) {
                        if (n2.isPriority()) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                long l1 = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();

                if (l1 > 0) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (l1 < 0) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });

        return combinedList;

    }
}
```

Note Repository class:

```java
public class NoteRepository {

    private String DB_NAME = "db_task";

    Context context;
    private RecurringDao recurringDao; 
    private LiveData<List<RecurringTask>> upcomingRecurringTasks;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> upcomingTasks;
    private CustomMediatorLiveData customMediatorLiveData;

    private NoteDatabase noteDatabase;

    public NoteRepository(Context context) {
        noteDatabase = NoteDatabase.getInstance(context);

        recurringDao = noteDatabase.recurringDao();

        upcomingRecurringTasks = recurringDao.getUpcomingRecurringTask();
        upcomingTasks = noteDatabase.daoAccess().fetchUpcomingTasks();

        this.context = context;

        customMediatorLiveData = new CustomMediatorLiveData(upcomingTasks, upcomingRecurringTasks);

    }

    public LiveData<List<Object>> getCustomMediatorLiveData() {
        return customMediatorLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<List<RecurringTask>> getUpcomingRecurringTasks() {
        return upcomingRecurringTasks;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> fetchUpcomingTasks() {
        return NoteDatabase.getInstance(context).daoAccess().fetchUpcomingTasks();
    }


}
```

I have tried using the `MediatorLiveData` object and add the two `LiveData` sources to it in the repository itself and the same issue persists.

What is the correct way to implement this? How to combine 2 `LiveData`s into a single `LiveData` that can be observed.

Comment: Do you mean modifying objects in list from `MediatorLiveData` affects objects in source livedatas? Because you never create any copies, just aggregate them in another list so that's expected.

Comment: @Pawel No, what I meant is when I combine the data sets from both the live data using the mediator live data. The combined data is producing anomalies. Ex. if there is a list of tasks in both the live data, after combining them, some of the tasks in the final list have the task date field changed to a random date. P.s. I am not modifying any of the objects through my code, I have only combined and sorted them based on their fields.

Comment: I don't know what to say, I can only advice to add some extra logging or run your `combineData` in debug step-by-step to pinpoint where the mixup happens